# Exporting an imported interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a number of templates in different directories - I define an interface for each so I can be sure that what I am referencing in my TypeScript code will be available in the template.

I would like to define an interface for each of them and then collate all of the interfaces in a single file that can be imported (so I can always just import that file and auto complete will show what interfaces are available).

However, I'm having trouble doing this. What I currently have:

`login/interface`:

```
export interface Index {
    error: string;
    value: string;
}
```

`interfaces.ts`:

```
import * as login from './login/interface';
export let View = {
    Login: login
};
```

`login.ts`:

```
import * as I from './interface';
...
let viewOutput: I.View.Login.Index = {
   ...
};
```

Results in:

> error TS2694: Namespace '"...interface"' has no exported member 'View'.

However, if I try to access `I.View.Login.Index` as a simple variable then I get:

> Property 'Index' does not exist on type 'typeof "...interface"'.

Which seems correct since the interface is not really a type, but it has been able to access `I.View.Login` to get that far.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong or missing here I'm afraid. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 26):

You can [re-export](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#re-exports) like so:

```
// interfaces.ts
export * from './login/interface';
export * from './something/interface';
```

And then:

```
// login.ts
import * as I from './interface';
let viewOutput: I.Index = { ... }
```

Another option is:

```
import * as login from './login/interface';
export { login as Login };
```

And then:

```
// login.ts
let viewOutput: I.Login.Index = { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you for this! What would I do to wrap it in a `View` object (e.g. `I.View.Login.Index`. That would allow me to basically name space my various view interfaces and I can't seem to figure out the syntax for that.

Comment: You might be able to do that using `export =`, though I don't think that it's a good idea